# Chrome ignores my iframe src and goes to the wrong page, how can I fix it?

Tags: html, iframe

Here is the code from my website
[view from the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KawLp.png)

And here is the view from the console
[view from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVt4Z.png)

For some reason chrome ignores the link set in the iframe and goes to http://google.com/support/cookies which results in an error

There were no scripts on the website that could possibly interrupt the loading of the iframe

I thought I had to use href but when I tried it, it didnt work

Comment: at least 2 problems, first your page return code 404 instead 200, second you need also send header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on response so it can be embeddable in iframe.

Comment: @Sergey92zp Ok so I changed the status code to 200 through php and added the header but for someone reason nothing worked. The same error still appears.

Comment: as it turned out problems is not mentioned one previously(but actually them still important for normal behaviour of iframe), here is breakdown of requests https://imgur.com/a/37kxphp you can see that your hosting provider using some bot protection, and for some reason it detect request for this page in iframe as malicious request, either ask provider to remove protection or change hosting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.